# Create multistep buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a multistep form with the following buttons:

[image]

But I have no clue on how to begin with this. Can someone help me on my way? Maybe a good resource? I'm also using bootstrap in my application.

For now I have:

[image]

My HTML looks like this:

```
    <ol class="multi-step">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="http://mydomain/nl/data-analysis/templates">
            <span class="number-circle">1</span>
            Maak een sjabloon        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="http://mydomain/nl/data-analysis/scheduler">
            <span class="number-circle">2</span>
            Plan je sjabloon        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="http://mydomain/nl/data-analysis/reports">
            <span class="number-circle">3</span>
            Bekijk de resultaten        </a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: is this a breadcrumb?

Comment: i suggest you look into form wizard, here is a bootstrap example https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/form-wizard-using-tabs

Comment: @ChandraShekhar, no it's not a breadcrumb. I've updated my topic with current status.

Comment: CSS Tricks have an article about achieving something similar with pseudo-elements. https://css-tricks.com/triangle-breadcrumbs/

Comment: Are you asking about how to change the look of your buttons or how to implement a multistep form?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
make use of pseudo elements

CSS

```
.multi-step{
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0;
}
.multi-step > li{
  display:inline-block;
  margin: auto 20px;
}
.multi-step > li > a{
  display:block;
  padding:10px 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  color:#fff;
  position: relative;
}
.multi-step > li > a::after,
.multi-step > li > a::before{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  height:0;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  width:0;
  border:19px solid red;
}
.multi-step > li > a::before{
  left:-35px;
  border-left-color:transparent;
}
.multi-step > li > a::after{
  right:-38px;
  border-color:transparent;
  border-left-color:red;
}
```

style accordingly

[reference link](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/dt4c35Lk/)

hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

So, in HTML everything that gets rendered on the page is just a rectangle of a varying size. It may not appear that way, but everything has a bounding box and it determines its presence on the page.

There are roundabout ways to create shapes (like giving something 50% `border-radius` just turns it into a circle), but they're just that and they aren't really ideal.

What you have for what would constitute shapes is SVG, where you draw a vector onto the page of your own specifications.

However, I question if what you're showing constitutes a "design" or just an element that happens to look a certain way.

---

The best solutions I can come up with:

1. Insert two elements and use the CSS `transform` property to `skew` one one way and one the other way:

```
<div id="bar">
  <div class="arrow">
    <a>asdf</a>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow">
    <a>hjkl</a>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow">
    <a>qwer</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
#bar {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}

.arrow a {
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.arrow::before {
  content: '';
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  display: block;
  transform: skew(45deg);
}

.arrow::after {
  content: '';
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  display: block;
  transform: skew(-45deg);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7nku4474/1

---

2. Use SVG to draw the shape:

```
<div id="bar">
  <a href="asdf">
    <svg fill="blue">
      <path d="M 0,0 L 200,0, L 250,50 L 200,100 L 0,100 L 50,50 Z">
      </path>
      <text x="125" y="50" font-size="12" fill="#fff" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="central">
        asdf
      </text>
    </svg>
  </a>

  <a href="asdf">
    <svg fill="blue">
      <path d="M 0,0 L 200,0, L 250,50 L 200,100 L 0,100 L 50,50 Z">
      </path>
      <text x="125" y="50" font-size="12" fill="#fff" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="central">
        hjkl
      </text>
    </svg>
  </a>

  <a href="asdf">
    <svg fill="blue">
      <path d="M 0,0 L 200,0, L 250,50 L 200,100 L 0,100 L 50,50 Z">
      </path>
      <text x="125" y="50" font-size="12" fill="#fff" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="central">
        qwer
      </text>
    </svg>
  </a>
</div>
```

```
#bar {
  display: flex;
}

#bar svg {
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#bar a:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1smpuL1r/